# Adjusting workspace size according image in clipboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have image in clipboard and would like to paste it into Adobe Illustrator new document. I don't know what is size of image, but I would like that new artboard would be created according to picture dimensions. Is it possible somehow adjust this functionality?

Comment: no, I don't think so, but you could create a document of any size, paste your image, then go to Object->Artboards->Fit to Artwork Bounds

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the way to adjust the artboard as your paste your image into it (a bit like Photoshop does) but there's another trick that is quite convenient in Illustrator.

---

1. You can go in the menu "Object", then "Artboards" and then select
   "Fit to artwork bounds"
2. You can also select a shape in your artboard and select the "Fit to
   selected art" to make your artboard the size of that shape. This can be useful if you need to add some extra margins around your image or a precise size; you can simply trace an empty rectangle and use it as the base to resize your artboard.

With this technique, you can simply copy-paste your image into Illustrator and use one of the above.

[image: fit adobe illustrator artboard to artwork]